# How to pass a function to a child component and use as an useState?

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have an component where i set a prop `darkMode` in a useState. I want to give this to the child component with onDarkmodeChange={darkMode}. This child gave this prop also to his child. In the toggle switch i want to use the prop onDarkmodeChange. But how am i supposed to use this? I tink i am doing something wrong because darkMode is not updated anymore.

```
export function PageLayout({ children }) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <Header onDarkModeChange={darkMode} />
  )
}

export function Header({ onDarkModeChange }) {
  return (
   <ToggleSwitch {... { onDarkModeChange }} />
  )
}

export function ToggleSwitch({ onDarkModeChange }) {
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = React.useState(onDarkModeChange)
  return (
    <label className={styles.component}>
      <input className={styles.input} type='checkbox' checked={isToggled} onChange={() => setIsToggled(!isToggled)} />
      <span className={cx(styles.switch, isToggled && styles.isActive)} />
    </label>
  )
}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer to this question, but for something like dark mode theming, you would be much better off using a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), rather than passing a state down to every component it's used in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not necessary to have the `isToggled` state since it's going to have the same value that the `darkMode` state. Also, I would move all the logic to the parent so that both children can access and manipulate that state, in case that it's necessary. Try this:

```
export function PageLayout({ children }) {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(false)

  const switchDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(currentDarkMode => !currentDarkMode)
  }

  return (
    <Header darkMode={darkMode} switchDarkMode={switchDarkMode} />
  )
}

export function Header({ darkMode, switchDarkMode }) {
  return (
   <ToggleSwitch darkMode={darkMode} switchDarkMode={switchDarkMode} />
  )
}

export function ToggleSwitch({ darkMode, switchDarkMode }) {
  return (
    <label className={styles.component}>
      <input className={styles.input} type='checkbox' checked={darkMode} onChange={switchDarkMode} />
      <span className={cx(styles.switch, darkMode && styles.isActive)} />
    </label>
  )
}
```